# Bitmap.createScaledBitmap create Image dull-low quality image

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` to Resize Image but as I have just checked it, It creates dull Image or say low quality image. Please let me know If I can get clear image.
I am using this method because I want to reduce photo size before uploading it to server.
**My Code is as below :**

```
    final int maxSize = 250;
    int outWidth;
    int outHeight;
    int inWidth = selectedImage.getWidth();
    int inHeight = selectedImage.getHeight();
    if (inWidth > inHeight) {
        outWidth = maxSize;
        outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
    } else {
        outHeight = maxSize;
        outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
    }

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage,
        outWidth, outHeight, false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    String strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: When you mention 'dull' do you mean 'null'?  Or do you mean that the image looks of low-quality or off?

Comment: @JaySnayder, It looks like low quality.

Comment: Depending on the original size of the image, reducing it down to such a small image will hurt the quality as mentioned.  I would suspect that working with the compression rates and if desired just modifying the inSampleSize by a factor of 2 or 4 as desired instead of just a static size.